# How do I install a Linux distribution from within Linux without rebooting?

Tags: system-installation, reboot

I have a working Linux PC, and I want to install a (probably different) Linux distribution on a disk that is currently unused (it's an SSD if that matters). The SSD will be connected via a SATA-to-USB-3 adapter. The challenging part is that I would rather not have to boot my PC into that SSD.

Notes:

- I don't mind setting up a virtual machine for use during installation, if that's necessary.
- The hardware is not particularly old, nor is there anything exotic on the system.
- Both distributions are versions of Devuan.

Comment: What you are searching for is called `bootstrapping`. Debian has [`debootstrap`](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap)  for this and it should also work for [Devuan](http://dev1galaxy.org/viewtopic.php?id=576). Never did it myself so far, so just links ....  In general, you are installing a whole system into a directory (the mounted drive) of you running OS by directly using the repos as source.

Comment: BTW `bootstrapping` is a far more general term than I first assumed. Nevertheless, a more detailed guide for debian can be found here: https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apds03.html.en

Comment: @FelixJN: Perhaps make these comments into an answer? Also, what about the installation of a boot loader, in addition to than just the files?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? You can update grub in current install & when you reboot, you can then choose your other install. Normally you have to use live installer to have partitions unmounted. But if another drive, you can use gparted and it will work. Better to use gpt whether UEFI or BIOS, but with UEFI you need an ESP - efi system partition or with BIOS a bios_grub partition, unformatted 1 or 2MB with bios_grub flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: This is the approach that Gentoo uses for installs.  Take a look at the Gentoo installation handbook (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Main_Page) -- there might be something there that you can generalize to whatever distribution you're trying to install.

Comment: @oldfred: Thanks. Do you have a link more specifically regarding ESP's?

Comment: @AndyDalton: Does Gentoo automate all of this stuff, or does it also involve a bunch of "manual labor"?

Comment: General info:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_drivers

Comment: _Does Gentoo automate [installation]?_ No, it's "manual labor."